# NDsolve with variable end-point

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I want to plot the solution a coupled ODEs as a function of the end point only.
Mathematica code:

```
tmax = 5;
rr = 1;
p = 0;
x[r_, t_, p_] = r Cos[(2 \[Pi])/tmax t + p];
z[r_, t_, p_] = r Sin[(2 \[Pi])/tmax t + p];
g[r_, t_, 
   p_] = ((1 + z[r, t, p]) D[x[r, t, p], t] - (I + x[r, t, p]) D[
     z[r, t, p], t])/(2 ((1 + z[r, t, p]^2) + (I + x[r, t, p]^2)));
b[r_, t_] = Sqrt[(1 + I) + r^2] t;
sol1 = NDSolve[{c1'[t] == -g[rr, t, p] Exp[-2 I b[rr, t] ] c2[t], 
    c2'[t] == g[rr, t, p] Exp[2 I b[rr, t]] c1[t], c1[0] == 1, 
    c2[0] == 0}, {c1, c2}, {t, 0, tmax}];
sol2 = NDSolve[{c1'[t] == -g[rr, t, p] Exp[-2 I b[rr, t] ] c2[t], 
    c2'[t] == g[rr, t, p] Exp[2 I b[rr, t]] c1[t], c1[0] == 0, 
    c2[0] == 1}, {c1, c2}, {t, 0, tmax}];
```

Then want to repeat this procedure for different `tmax` and plot `LogPlot[Evaluate[{{Abs[c2[t]/c1[t]]} /. sol1, {Abs[c1[t]/c2[t]]} /. 
    sol2}], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> Full]`

Many thanks to the helpers

EDIT:

In block diagram this is what I want:

Given coupled ODEs that are dependent on `tmax` both as the end-point and as a parameter, find the solution for each `tmax`, `c1_tmax[t] c2_tmax[t]`

define the functions:

```
c1[tmax]=c1_tmax[tmax]

c2[tmax]=c2_tmax[tmax]
```

plot `c2[tmax]/c1[tmax]` for `{tmax,0,20}`

Here's what I finally did (I hope it actually does it):

```
rr = 0.8;
p = 0;
x[r_, t_, p_] = r Cos[(2 \[Pi])/tmax t + p];
z[r_, t_, p_] = r Sin[(2 \[Pi])/tmax t + p];
g[r_, t_, 
   p_] = ((1 + z[r, t, p]) D[x[r, t, p], t] - (I + x[r, t, p]) D[
     z[r, t, p], t])/(2 ((1 + z[r, t, p]^2) + (I + x[r, t, p]^2)));
b[r_, t_] = Sqrt[(1 + I) + r^2] t;
sol1 = ParametricNDSolve[{c1'[
      t] == -g[rr, t, p] Exp[-2 I b[rr, t] ] c2[t], 
    c2'[t] == g[rr, t, p] Exp[2 I b[rr, t]] c1[t], c1[0] == 1, 
    c2[0] == 0}, {c1, c2}, {t, 0, tmax}, {tmax}];
sol2 = ParametricNDSolve[{c1'[
      t] == -g[rr, t, p] Exp[-2 I b[rr, t] ] c2[t], 
    c2'[t] == g[rr, t, p] Exp[2 I b[rr, t]] c1[t], c1[0] == 0, 
    c2[0] == 1}, {c1, c2}, {t, 0, tmax}, {tmax}];
LogPlot[Evaluate[{{Abs[c2[tmax][tmax]/c1[tmax][tmax]]} /. 
    sol1, {Abs[c1[tmax][tmax]/c2[tmax][tmax]]} /. sol2}], {tmax, 0, 
  20}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {10^-3, 10^3}}]
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html).

Comment: Also [this Wolfram training video](http://www.wolfram.com/training/videos/GEN302/) has a bit on `FunctionInterpolation` that is very relevant

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as mentioned in the comments, you can go either of two ways. With your definitions (note I omitted `tmax`):

```
rr = 1;
p = 0;
x[r_, t_, p_] = r Cos[(2 π)/tmax t + p];
z[r_, t_, p_] = r Sin[(2 π)/tmax t + p];
g[r_, t_, p_] = ((1 + z[r, t, p]) D[x[r, t, p], t] - (I + x[r, t, p]) D[
       z[r, t, p], t])/(2 ((1 + z[r, t, p]^2) + (I + x[r, t, p]^2)));
b[r_, t_] = Sqrt[(1 + I) + r^2] t;
```

#### Using NDSolve

```
sol1[tmax_] /; tmax > 0 := 
  Evaluate@NDSolve[{c1'[t] == -g[rr, t, p] Exp[-2 I b[rr, t]] c2[t], 
     c2'[t] == g[rr, t, p] Exp[2 I b[rr, t]] c1[t], c1[0] == 1, 
     c2[0] == 0}, {c1, c2}, {t, 0, tmax}];
sol2[tmax_] /; tmax > 0 := 
  Evaluate@NDSolve[{c1'[t] == -g[rr, t, p] Exp[-2 I b[rr, t]] c2[t], 
     c2'[t] == g[rr, t, p] Exp[2 I b[rr, t]] c1[t], c1[0] == 0, 
     c2[0] == 1}, {c1, c2}, {t, 0, tmax}];
```

you can now solve for every initial condition

```
f1[t_, tmax_] := (Abs[c2[t]/c1[t]] /. Flatten@sol1[tmax]);
f2[t_, tmax_] := (Abs[c2[t]/c1[t]] /. Flatten@sol2[tmax]);
```

and create a plot for a range of `tmax` from 1 to 5:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Table[
    LogPlot[
     Evaluate[{f1[t, tmax], f2[t, tmax]}], {t, 0, tmax},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, All},
     PlotLabel -> "tmax = " <> ToString@tmax], 
    {tmax, 0.5, 5, .1}] // Export["test.gif", #] &;]
```

> {5.88, Null}

and here's how it looks:

[image]

#### Using ParametricNDSolve

```
sol11 = ParametricNDSolve[{c1'[
      t] == -g[rr, t, p] Exp[-2 I b[rr, t]] c2[t], 
    c2'[t] == g[rr, t, p] Exp[2 I b[rr, t]] c1[t], c1[0] == 1, 
    c2[0] == 0}, {c1, c2}, {t, 0, tmax}, {tmax}];
sol12 = ParametricNDSolve[{c1'[
      t] == -g[rr, t, p] Exp[-2 I b[rr, t]] c2[t], 
    c2'[t] == g[rr, t, p] Exp[2 I b[rr, t]] c1[t], c1[0] == 0, 
    c2[0] == 1}, {c1, c2}, {t, 0, tmax}, {tmax}];
```

now you define the functions somewhat differently:

```
g1[t_, tmax_] := Abs[Evaluate[c2[tmax][t]/c1[tmax][t]]] /. sol11;
g2[t_, tmax_] := Abs[Evaluate[c2[tmax][t]/c1[tmax][t]]] /. sol12;
```

and again do the same:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Table[
    LogPlot[
     Evaluate[{g1[t, tmax], g2[t, tmax]}], {t, 0, tmax},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, All},
     PlotLabel -> "tmax = " <> ToString@tmax], 
    {tmax, 0.5, 5, .1}] // Export["test2.gif", #] &;]
```

> {6.17, Null}

and you get the same plot:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks,but this plot the solution upto tmax whereas I wanted the solutions as function of tmax. I have clarified my request (and proposed solution) in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
 Manipulate[
  tmax = endpoint;

   sol1 = NDSolve[{c1'[t] == -g[rr, t, p] Exp[-2 I b[rr, t]] c2[t], 
     c2'[t] == g[rr, t, p] Exp[2 I b[rr, t]] c1[t], c1[0] == 1, 
     c2[0] == 0}, {c1, c2}, {t, 0, tmax}];
  sol2 = NDSolve[{c1'[t] == -g[rr, t, p] Exp[-2 I b[rr, t]] c2[t], 
     c2'[t] == g[rr, t, p] Exp[2 I b[rr, t]] c1[t], c1[0] == 0, 
     c2[0] == 1}, {c1, c2}, {t, 0, tmax}];

  LogPlot[Evaluate[{{Abs[c2[t]/c1[t]]} /. sol1, {Abs[c1[t]/c2[t]]} /.sol2}],
   {t, 0, tmax},PlotRange -> Full],

 {{endpoint, 5}, $MachineEpsilon, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"},

  Initialization :> {rr = 1,
    p = 0,
    x[r_, t_, p_] = r Cos[(2 \[Pi])/tmax t + p],
    z[r_, t_, p_] = r Sin[(2 \[Pi])/tmax t + p],
    g[r_, t_, p_] = ((1 + z[r, t, p]) D[x[r, t, p], t] - (I + x[r, t, p]) D[
          z[r, t, p], t])/(2 ((1 + z[r, t, p]^2) + (I + x[r, t, p]^2))),
    b[r_, t_] = Sqrt[(1 + I) + r^2] t
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Thank, but not quite.
I want to solves the coupled ODEs which are dependent on tmax both in the equations themselves and in the end point of the integration. Then I'd like to take the different solution to different tmax's and present it as a function of tmax only.

Comment: That's not what you said in your original post though:"I want to repeat this procedure for different `tmax` and plot `LogPlot[CODE, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> Full]` ."

Comment: Noted, I was a bit unclear. I've rephrased the question.